# Zip complete folder using System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one example where all the files in the folder are zipped but not the folder itself .[This code is from MSDN]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
namespace zip
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string directoryPath = @"c ------------------------------------------------------------------------ :\users\public\reports";
            DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in directorySelected.GetFiles())
            {
                Compress(fileToCompress);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
            {
                Decompress(fileToDecompress);
            }
        }

        public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
        {
            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
            {
                if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
                {
                    using
                      (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                    {
                        using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                            Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.", fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), compressedFileStream.Length.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
        {
            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
            {
                string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
                string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);
                using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory ?

Comment: So you need to compress each file in the source folder excluding the directory itself ?

Comment: Because @PurpleXenon, That class isn't available earlier than .net 4.5.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can zip a complete folder using System.IO.Compression, you can only compress files inside  the folder. You can use DotNetZip instead. It is a 100% managed code library that can be used in any .NET application - Console, Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, Sharepoint, Web services apps, and so on.

Download developer's kit package from http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx.

Reference necessaries including DotNetZip DLL in your application and do follows:

```
string[] MainDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(""c:\users\public\reports");

for (int i = 0; i < MainDirs.Length; i++)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
        zip.AddDirectory(MainDirs[i]);
        zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
        zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
        zip.Save(string.Format("test{0}.zip", i));   
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks